# How to group by X minute increments in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have data set that looks like the following :

```
Name, Timestamp, Period, Value
Apple, 2012-03-22 00:00:00.000, 10, 34
Apple, 2012-03-22 00:06:00.000, 10, 23
Orange, 2012-03-22 00:00:00.000, 5, 3
Orange, 2012-03-22 00:08:00.000, 5, 45
```

Where the column period is the N number of minutes it should be grouped by per hour. So for example Apple should be grouped on 1:10, 1:20, 1:30 ex where Orange is 1:05, 1:10 ect. I would also like to average the Value column over each of these increments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the assumptions that

- `Period` is whole integer and a divisor of 60
- for two rows, if `Name` is the same, `Period` is the same

the following should do

```
SELECT
    name,
    date_trunc('minute', timestamp_column)
      - interval '1' minute * (minute(timestamp_column) % period)
      AS timestamp_rounded,
    avg(value)
FROM ...
GROUP BY 1, 2
```